# Memory leak in nodejs zlib

Tags: node.js, linux

I am doing some tests using zlib provided by nodejs.

[image]
[image]

When I called the deflate function 5000 times in a loop, a memory leak occurred. And the brk function was called more than 10000 times in Linux(strace -cfe mmap,munmap,mprotect,brk -p {process Id} ).

However, when I called 5000 every 1 second using setInterval, there was no memory leak. And the brk function occurred much less in Linux.

[image]
[image]

In nodejs, the same number is called 5000, but why is the number of calls of brk function different in Linux?
I guess it's like reusing memory space in Linux. Is this correct? If not, what is the exact cause?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely, you are seeing some side effect of the garbage collector.  Analyzing this requires more more information than you've posted here, but if I were to hazard an educated guess, NodeJS (or v8 via libuv) probably does an opportunistic GC at the bottom of the event loop, to collect garbage in at least their shortest-lived pool.

When you are running this in a loop, you never fall off the event loop, which means that garbage collection probably has fewer opportunities to run.  It probably runs based on a timer or allocation counter, and almost certainly during the memory allocator when there is memory pressure.

Run it in your loop for a few hundred thousand iterations, I bet it stabilizes the total process allocation at some point.